# Increment a variable without using static keyword

Tags: java, static

Here I am using static keyword to instantiate a variable And I am calling the variable using two different Objects.I want to print the result as 1 and 2 without using the static keyword.Thanks in advance.

```
public class Test {
    static int a = 1;

    public void meth() {
        System.out.println(a);
        a = a + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test a = new Test();
        Test b = new Test();
        a.meth(); //prints 1
        b.meth(); //prints 2
    }

}
```

Comment: Assignment question?

Comment: When you remove the static keyword, the value of a is no longer shared amon the two instances of ``Test``. Therefore, your output will be ``1 1`` as each instance has its own counting variable.

Comment: `a` is shared among all instances. If you remove `static`, it'll be associated with each instance. Create one instance and call `meth` twice - The first call will print 1, the second will print 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `static` keyword, you need to share an `int` variable in your two instances of `Test`.

For example, using `AtomicInteger` as a mutable wrapper for `int` and providing the object when constructing `Test`:

```
public class Test {
    private final AtomicInteger a;
    // + constructor setting a + getter

    public void increment() {
        a.incrementAndGet();
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger()
        Test a = new Test(i);
        Test b = new Test(i);

        System.out.println(i.get()); // prints 0
        a.increment();
        System.out.println(i.get()); // prints 1
        b.increment();
        System.out.println(i.get()); // prints 2

    }
}
```